# Define a variable for a ":" slice

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I want to define a function that will operate on a part of a dataframe if another variable is set, or on the full dataframe otherwhile. For instance :

```
def mean_loc(df, col_name, idx=None):
    if idx is not None:
        return df.loc[idx, col_name].mean()
    else:
        return df[col_name].mean()
```

This works just fine but I was wondering if this was possible to do something like that :

```
def mean_loc_2(df, col_name, idx=None):
    if idx is None:
        idx = :
    return df.loc[idx, col_name].mean()
```

This of course does not work but I was wondering if there existed a bypass ? If I do `idx = df.index`, the evaluation of `df.loc[df.index, col_name]` is way longer than doing `df.loc[:, col_name]`. I've tried working with `slice` from the built-in functions by doing `idx = slice(len(df))` but without any success (it's also longer and does not work for DateTime indexes).

Does anyone know how to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 2):

`:` is not a value; it's part of Python's syntax. What you want is the `slice` object that the `:` syntax represents.

```
if idx is None:
    idx = slice(None)  # sadly, slice() does not work
```

Since a `slice` object is immutable, it's safe to use one as the default parameter value.

```
def mean_loc_2(df, col_name, idx=slice(None)):
    return df.loc[idx, col_name].mean()
```